# Is there a tool to extract all possible paths between two locations in code?

Tags: c++, code-analysis, debugging

I am debugging a bug in C++ code that I did not write. I know that between location A and B in the source, something happened to produce this unexpected output. This is often the only information I have to begin with.

It occurred to me that most of the time I spend on tracking down bugs is not trying to comprehend logic, but rather trying to identify the possible routes between A and B. Is there a tool out there to do this for me?

Specifics:

- Works with C++ source code
- Provides information of all possible paths from A to B that is specified in code
- Does not require usage of breakpoints. I.e. it can analyse the code without running it
- (Preferably) a small application

Comment: "preferably a small application"?  It has to contain a full C++ parser and analysis engine.  "Small" is not the right adjective here.

Comment: Use any of the many free all tree programs and ignore the parts you don't want. That's the quickest & simplest way.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you are going to a tool that does exactly what you want out of the box.   You can collect this information from a C++ "parser" that knows how to resolve C++ names fully (that means a full C++ front end).

Our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit with its C++ Front End](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html?site=softwarerecs) can provide this information.

The pair comprise a full-blown C++ parsing and static analysis engine, which can compute control-flows (which OP wants) and dataflows (which OP does not need) and call graphs.  See the control/data flow SVG sample at the site page.

With that control flow information, OP could code a control flow graph walk starting at "point A" and finding different routes to "point B".   This will be a quite straightforward depth-first search in the control flow graph if points A and B are in the same function.   If they are in different functions fA and fB, he will need to find some shared caller-parent S of fA and fB, such that S calls fA, and then trace the control flow path from A to B across the call graph.  This is more complicated but is probably only a few pages of code if you know what you are doing.   It is should be obvious that learning how to use a tool such as DMS is not something you do in afternoon; anything that can handle C++ is already very sophisticated and handles tons of details.

Summary:

- Full parser for various C++ dialects including GCC and MS, up through C++14 (with C++17 in the works)
- Builds function local control (and dataflow) graphs
- Can build call tree
- Requires custom code to extract facts of interest about C++ programs

You can probably customize Clang or GCC to do this too, but I suspect it is not an easy task, and you'll face the same kind of learning curve problem you would face with DMS, for the same reasons.   GCC has a reputation for being very hard to work with.  I have no experience with Clang; I don't think it computes control flow graphs on C++ code, but rather on the LLVM back end, so you'd have to compute control flow on LLVM graphs and then backtrace into the C++ source code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [CppDepend](http://www.cppdepend.com) to track all the possible paths between A and B.
The DSM and the dependency graph are provided to understand the dependencies between two or many elements.